# Is it possible to modify this ClickOnce error message?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, clickonce

I am getting the following message while installing my application:

> You cannot start application from this location because it is already installed from a different location.

Is there any way to modify this error text?

Comment: Do you want to be able to install the application successfully or do you want to edit the error-description that comes when that application is not able to install?  Please be more clear in your questions.

Comment: I want to modify the error description.

Comment: Pankaj, please stop adding C# tags; this question is not about C#. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`<customErrorReporting>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679074.aspx) in the ClickOnce manifest file to accomplish this, if you can track down the actual exception that is occurring. You'll need an ASP site capable of decoding the error information it sends you, and there's not a whole lot of documentation on this matter.

Comment: can you plz share the link for same ?

Comment: The customErrorReporting tag in my answer can be clicked and links to the MSDN docs.